# Version of game to best experience Modern Warfare single-player campaigns and multiplayer modes?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I own a PS3 and have never played Modern Warfare games before. Which version of the Modern Warfare games would give me the essential Modern Warfare experience?
Do I need to play the latest version to do this? If not, what version would be best?

Based on reviews that are out there it seems like the engine that MW3 is based on hasn't changed much. Will I get any sort of play experience boost by playing MW3?

Comment: I'm not sure there's much of a difference between [the previous question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/36879/8366) and this one; in any event, it is probably better to edit the original question rather than creating a new one.

Comment: I thought that since it was closed that I should start a new question. Sorry...

Comment: It's OK ... the "closed" description is something we've been struggling to explain better. On Stack Exchange sites, "closed" means "closed to answers until the question is revised further". You always have the option to edit your question, and if it meets the site's standards, people can vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 3):

The three Modern Warfare games share a plot, but the plot tends to be pretty [nonsensical](http://www.dorkly.com/article/27495/five-rejected-modern-warfare-3-storylines).  There are [plot summaries](http://www.gamespot.com/video/modern-warfare-story-recap-choose-your-own-adventure-version-6344012) online if you want to jump into MW3 without playing the first two.

As far as online goes, there are still many people playing the first two Modern Warfare games, although the [majority of people](http://www.computerandvideogames.com/326381/modern-warfare-3-tops-xbox-live-activity/) are now playing Modern Warfare 3.  (These are Xbox Live numbers, although you can assume PSN is similar).

The three games share a very similar engine and very similar gameplay.  Skills from playing one online generally transfer to other games in the series.

I would say that you could almost consider Modern Warfare to be the "Madden" of shooter games - there's one every year, and the gameplay tweaks are generally of interest to the hardcore series player.

Don't forget also that in between Modern Warfare and Modern Warfare 2 was Call of Duty: World at War, and between Modern Warfare 2 and Modern Warfare 3 was Call of Duty: Black Ops.  World at War and Black Ops don't share the same storyline as the MW series, but they still have similar gameplay and online components.  They were developed by a different company (Infinity Ward does Modern Warfare, Treyarch the others).  Some people have a preference for one company's work over the other's.

Which you choose is really up to you; price-wise the older versions are considerably cheaper, however, the bulk of the support and the gamers are likely to be on Modern Warfare 3.  More players generally means more game lobbies, and a better likelihood of a good multiplayer experience, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that PC players are still playing COD4 a lot more than MW2, BO or MW3 still.  I've dived back into the game and I'm still seeing a lot of servers out there with a lot of people playing.

Comment: http://store.steampowered.com/stats/ - at least in terms of Steam stats, MW3 outpaces the next highest CoD game (MW2) by a factor of 4 as of right now (the stats are live, so you might see different numbers when you click that link)

Comment: But that's through Steam.  COD4 isn't really a Steam game so their stats are not getting the whole picture.